# Batch file not comparing strings within for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that will read a spreadsheet, and use data from that sheet to update HTML files by adding to their contents at specific locations within the file. Why a spreadsheet? Because then I can store the file name, directory, and text to add all in one place, parse it into an array, and work through the sheet sequentially to update arbitrary numbers of files at once.

Unfortuantly, while the code reading the spreadsheet works fine, the part which should insert the code is not. It also, somehow, ignores escape characters.

Here's what I've done so far.

EDIT: I followed this suggestion "if "!line!"=="%replaced%"", it did not work.

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

cd /D "%~dp0data"

set /a heartoflorkan=0
for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('Type "link.csv"') do (
    set /a heartoflorkan+=1
    set "outputa[!heartoflorkan!]=%%a"
)

For /L %%i in (1,1,%heartoflorkan%) Do (
    set "replaced=!outputa[%%i]!"
    call :writer
)
pause
goto:eof


:writer

cd /D "%~dp0"
set "replace=^<p class="AutoUpdateTag"^>History^<p^>"

set "source=infoboxtest"
set "target=text"

set flag=0

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" %source%.html') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if "%line%"=="%replace%" (
        set "line=!replaced!"
        set flag=1
    )
    if defined line echo !line! >> %target%.tmp
    if "!flag!"=="1" (
        echo !replace! >> %target%.tmp
        set flag=0
    )
) 

del %source%.html
rename %target%.tmp %source%.html
goto:eof
```

This will successfully recreate the HTML file I'm using for testing, but will not insert the line contained within %repalced% as expected. It's not outputting a null either, %replaced% is being set correctly. I think that `if "%line%"=="%replace%"` isn't performing its comparison operation, but I'm not sure why that would be.

Additionally, I was originally using a commented-out line of code as the marker rather than History

, but for some reason, I couldn't get this to type an exclamation point, even when escaping the character correctly via `^^!`.

Any ideas? Or even other/better ways to insert text into 1000s of files at a time?

Edit 2: For those who asked, [here](https://pastebin.com/qZuS3w2z) is the HTML file I am testing with. And since the CSV I am working with right now is just one line, here it is.
`testdir,infoboxtest,^<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-Gy4Zw1pGo"^>linkus injected^</a^>`

I've been informed that I may not need to escape the > < in the csv. However, since no text at all is being replaced, and logically the script would just type the escape carrots out too, I do not think that is my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected) Specifically, since you're setting and using `%line%` inside of the same set of parentheses, you need to change the line to `if "!line!"=="%replaced%"`.

Comment: I gave that a shot, and while it did not break the script, it still is not replacing the text.

Comment: My analysis of this convolution is that the contents of `link.csv` shuld be inserted before the line `<p class="AutoUpdateTag">History<p>`  - is that correct? If not, please explain what the process is expected to do, together with a small "before" and "after" sample of data, AND explain what you mean by `It's not outputting a null either`

Comment: @Magoo "My analysis of this convolution is that the contents of link.csv shuld be inserted before the line <p class="AutoUpdateTag">History<p> - is that correct?" Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. By "It's not outputting a null either" I mean there's no blank line, null character, or space as I usually get when batch echos a unset variable to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q73594275.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q73594275_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "targetstring=<p class="AutoUpdateTag">History<p>"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%b IN ('find /v /n "" ^<"%filename1%"') DO (
 IF "%%c"=="" (ECHO.) ELSE (
  IF "%%c"=="%targetstring%" TYPE "%filename2%"
  ECHO %%c
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"


GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Use `find` with `/n` to number each line that contains `/v` not *nothing* which simply numbers each line with a prefix `[linenumber]`.

Read each line, assigning `[linenumber` to `%%b` and the real data (which may be *empty*) to `%%c`. If `%%c` is empty, `echo` an empty line. Otherwise, check whether it's the target. If so, insert the data from the second file; then `echo` the line regardless.

Obviously, `outfile` can't be the same as the `filename1` or `filename2`.

Note that since the target line will remain in the output file, running the batch on the resulting file will continue to insert the required data over and over again.

Suggest that the output file is either in another directory or is in the source directory with another extension, given the plan to apply it to multiple files.